# When bricks with bottom holes were released?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I always try to build my sets with bricks from that era. The older ones and their release dates are pretty well known but what about that D variant in the picture with bottom pin holes ie. the modern LEGO block? When did we start to get them? From my understanding 80s sets did not have them yet but were they available already in the beginning of 90s?

[image: Some LEGO variations]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to identify the source of the photo.

Comment: @shoover I took the photo myself :)

Comment: Do you mean "hollow tubes" when you say "bottom holes"? Then TLG has gone a bit back-and-forth on that for certain elements, and never considered them different elements, so they might have been mixed in some sets - and I have no year(s) for when it was (re-)inroduced/dropped for specific elements.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Around the 90s is a pretty big timespan. The 1995 social media quote is a bit better but there is no link to any social media post it uses as source. Also, would be great to get a more direct answer from a reputable source.

Comment: I don't see the cross support on C, you're missed 1 out. Was going to say that all of what I call pillars, not knowing that hollow in future, others call them tubes, have cross support, but now see 1×8 only on 1 2 4 6 & 7.